# Retornar somente parte do campo SQL na pesquisa

Tags: sql, sql-server

Queria retornar na consulta somente os valores que estão entre parenteses no campo da tabela.

```
SELECT F2 FROM [dbo].[Vestcasa_Ranking_Produtos_Custo_]


F2
Airtom..(635)
paulo victo r.. (234) 
Antonio.. (459)
```

BUSCAR ASSIM

```
635
234
459
```

Comment: pergunta muito ampla, não consigo entender o que deseja.

Comment: Do conteúdo dos campos da sua busca você quer retornar apenas o que está entre parenteses é isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teste desta forma:

```
Select
    SUBSTRING(F2,CHARINDEX('(',F2)+1 ,CHARINDEX(')',F2)-CHARINDEX('(',F2)-1)  
from 
    [dbo].[Vestcasa_Ranking_Produtos_Custo_]
```